# Traversing the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I have some bookmarks that are displayed as pages.  I need to search these pages for a particular page in this case - page with id "social_page".

So to start, I grab the containing div

```
var bookmark_fill = document.getElementById( 'bookmark_fill' );
```

How do I best traverse the "pages" in bookmark_fill?  This simple case below has only 2 pages.

[image]

Comment: With jQuery.  No, I'm not trolling.  Seriously. jQuery makes this trivial.  Unless you're doing this as a learning experience?  In that case Jon Resig's first book Pro JavaScript Techniques goes into all the gory details of dom traversal

Comment: jQuery comes to mind: $("bookmark_link") will give them.

Comment: @AdamRackis given a modern browser, it's not so bad. With native byClass and the various Array# iteration functions, you can do pretty much anything trivially out of the box.

Comment: I agree with @Esailija. The browser doesn't event need to be very modern. IE8 supports `querySelector/querySelectorAll`. Even without those, most DOM selection is trivial.

Comment: @amnotiam - native dom traveral may be trivial, but it's also tedious.  jQuery makes it fun (both statements of course IMO only)

Comment: @AdamRackis: I personally don't find it tedious, but that's me. And much of the time jQuery/Sizzle is using `querySelectorAll` anyway.

Comment: @amnotiam - that's because you're much smarter than me, and can easily  tame the beastly dom :)

Comment: @AdamRackis: Me isn't no smarter then you is. Me just likes me DOM. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var socialPage = document.getElementById("social_page");
```

because ID's are supposed to be unique.

Comment: why do I try to make my life hard?...ummm thanks for some common sense.

Answer (score 1):

To get your bookmark_fill node:

```
var bookFill = document.getElementById("bookmark_fill");
```

To get all the pages in there, you can use the `getElementsByClassName` method

```
var allBookMarkPages = bookFill.getElementsByClassName("bookmark_page");

for (var i = 0, max = allBookMarkPages.length; i < max; i++) {
    var allLinks = allBookMarkPages[i].getElementsByClassName("bookmark");
}
```